# aws EC2 linux unable to open inbound ports

Tags: linux, security, amazon-ec2, rule, inbound

I am trying to run a web server on an EC2 linux instance (free tier), so I followed the instructions to open the port but was unsuccessful getting it to work. My server is running locally and I can access it.

The steps I took are:

1. Go to my security group.
2. Add inbound rule: custom tcp, port 8080, from anywhere.
3. I clicked saved.

However, it didn't seem to work. The only port that does work is 22. Just to verify, I tested on `https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/`

Anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Are you actually running an app on port 8080? What did you install and configure?

Comment: Yes I am.. Wildfly. I can curl localy and retrieve results.

Comment: http://blog.arungupta.me/bind-wildfly-different-ip-address-multihomed/

Answer (score 0):

Since you can curl locally and you have added the inbound tcp rules in the security group, it is probably because of the firewall. Go to your instance, and edit your firewall to open the port 8080.